# Sudden transparent chat windows on google chat client

Tags: windows-7, google-talk

A few days ago, my Google Talk client somehow lost the ability to display the text in the chat window:

[image: screenshot]

Seems that someone already asked for assistance regarding this issue back in 2010 received no answer: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chat/DenwPvMrFrU/iEGxvdnzD-0J

I uninstalled and completely purged the Google talk software with Revo Uninstaller. Next, I rebooted. Then, I installed Google Talk with the latest version. The problem persists.

I am running Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems like a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I'll answer it anyway.

If anyone is having this issue, clear your browser history until the beginning of time, close out of Chrome, open Chrome again, and sign in to gmail.  You should be able to see the text.

Comment: Please explain why clearing the browser history will fix the problem.